# How do I convert DER Format certificate x509 into human readable format?

Tags: javascript, certificate, x509certificate, x509certificate2, der

How can I convert a DER Format certificate x509 into a human readable format in JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript does not provide a method to parse certificate fields. You need to use a library like [forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#x509). I think you need something like this

```
var certAsn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(certDer)
var cert = forge.pki.certificateFromAsn1(certAsn1);
console.log(cert.serialNumber);
```

Comment: Probably your data is not in DER format or you have an encoding issue. Please update your question and add the code you are using, the entire error message and the example data you are using. If not, it is not possible to determine the cause

Comment: var pki = forge.pki;
var certpem="-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----------END CERTIFICATE-----";
var cert = pki.certificateFromPem(certpem);
console.log("certificat" + cert.validity.notBefore);
console.log("certificat" + cert.validity.notAfter);
console.log("certificat" + cert.serialNumber);. it works but NOW I don't know  how can I get the issuerCN and CN and I have  a DER in format Hex

Comment: Do not paste code into comments because it is difficult to read it. Just edit your question and add the information

Comment: To load DER content encoded as HEX, you will need first to decode it. Forge has functions to do it, or look at this site. To load the issuer info try to inspect the javascript object looking for a 'issuer' property or a 'getIssuer()` method. The CN should be a property of that object

Comment: thanks ,  it work now  IssuerCN like this : cert.issuer.getField('CN').value);   and CN  like this : cert.subject.getField('CN').value); . NOW  I have another question please How can I parse DER Hex to PEM  ??? thank you very much

Comment: Basically you have to convert HEX-->Binary-->Base64 and add PEM header and footer (`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`, `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`). It is recommended in Stack Overflow to create a new Post for each question, and add the code used so people could find the errors

Comment: See [doc](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#x509) Pem to Cert: `var cert = forge.pki.certificateFromPem(pem);` Public Key to PEM: `var pem = forge.pki.publicKeyToPem(cert.publicKey);`